# unique identifier between parent page and child page c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, guid

I am trying to pass unique identifier(GUID) from parent page to child page. On child page doing some dml operations. While closing child page i need to pass again that GUID back to parent page. If GUID matches based on that will load gridview

```
string UniqueId;            
UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string url = string.Format("LookUpRTD.aspx?UniqueId={0}",UniqueId) + "&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=700";     
string script = "$(document).ready(function() {tb_show('LookUpRTD', '" + url + "', null);});";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "", script, true);
```

whats the best way yo maintain GUID on parent page to compare after child page close?.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2:**
Try this:

Add a TextBox control on your parent page as

```
<asp:textbox id="Txtparent" runat="Server" xmlns:asp="#unknown" />
```

and set its value from the child page as

```
window.opener.document.forms[0].getElementById('Txtparent').value ="Value From Popup Page";
```

**Edit 1:**

Use session variables to store and get data anytime during valid user's session.

For setting value in Session variable use below code:

```
Session["UniqueId"] = strUniqueId;
```

For getting value from Session variable use below code:

```
strUniqueId = Convert.ToString(Session["UniqueId"]);
```

Comment: we are not allowed to use session variables .